# Programmatically get relation between tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

Assume that I have 3 tables namely `sales_order` , `sales_order_items` , `invoice` and set ON UPDATE = NO ACTION ON DELETE = NO ACTION.

Now I need to have the ability do delete the sales order. But if there is a relation exists in any other table it means that that sales order is used somewhere else and i need to prevent deletion.

Ex: I have sales_order_id = 34 , I want to check its exists in any other tables.

Previously to achieve the same thing I used transactions, something like below

```
$db = new database();

//start transaction

$db->start_trans();

//try to delete the sales order with ID = 34
$db->exec( 'DELETE FROM SALES_ORDER WHERE ID = 34' );

//check transaction success or failure 

if( $db->trans_status() == true ){

 //THERE IS NO RELATION EXISTS
 //ROLLBACK
 $db->rollback_trans();

 #Soft Delete the record     
 $db->exec( 'UPDATE sales_order SET is_deleted = 1 WHERE id = 34' );

}else{

 //RELATION EXISTS FOR ID = 34 IN SOME OTHER TABLES
}
```

the above code works, but the problem is with `sales_order_items`. Because it is a child table of `sales_order` and if it have contents then the transaction will fail and will try to execute the else part.

But in fact `sales_order_items` is a property of `sales_order` and I need to DELETE that particular sales_order (don't care about items).

I am expecting something like this

```
$relations = $db->get_relation( 'sales_order.id', '34' );
```

Expected Output

```
array( 'sales_order_items','invoice','another_table' .... );
```

**Note: The above is an example only, I have number of tables and it's not possible to go through each table and check `ID`  exists.**

Comment: why are you not using `on delete cascade` and then you're set emulating its behavior anyway through your application?

Comment: Actually there is no hard `deletion` .

Comment: the fact that you used the "DELETE" keyword mislead me. Now i understand.

Comment: @STTLCU I am sorry about that :)  i think that i need to join hand with php inorder to solve the problem. May be some kind of loops.

Comment: I lost the point: you need to mark row as deleted in both cases - when it is affected or not affected by foreign key constraint. So what is the problem? You just run `UPDATE sales_order SET is_deleted = 1 WHERE id = 34`.

Comment: @revoua Not actually, If relation exists in `invoice` table, i want to prevent deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Revoua for providing a good answer. Here is little modified version to suite my needs. Please correct me if it have some better way.

```
function check_relation( $table_name , $table_column ,$table_value ){

        //Get relation tables
        $qry = "SELECT  table_name,
                column_name,
                referenced_table_name,
                referenced_column_name 
                FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
                WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = ?
                AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME is not null
                AND referenced_table_name = ?
                AND referenced_column_name = ?";

        $db = $this->crm->db;

        //database name
        $database = $db->dbprefix.$db->database;

        //predefined array to store table names
        $related_tables = array();

        //execute the query 
        $qry = $db->query( $qry , array( $database , $table_name ,$table_column ) );

        unset($database);

        //Make sure that query is success
        if( $qry != FALSE && $qry->row_count() > 0 ){

            //Get as array
            $result = $qry->to_array();
            unset($qry);

            foreach( $result as $result_item ){

                //Get count based on table_value
                $qry = "SELECT COUNT(*)as total FROM ".$result_item['table_name']." WHERE ".$result_item['column_name']." = ? and is_del = 0";
                $qry = $db->query($qry,array($table_value));

                if( $qry!= FALSE && $qry->row_count() > 0 ) {

                    $qry = $qry->to_array(1);

                    //There are some entries ..
                    if( intval($qry['total']) > 0 ){        
                        $related_tables[] = $result_item['table_name'];
                    }

                }


            }

            return $related_tables;

        }else{
            return $related_tables;
        }

    }
```

### Usage:

```
$relation = $db->check_relation("SALES_ORDER","ID",34);
```

var_dump( $relation ) ==>

```
array( 'SALES_ORDER_ITEM','INVOICE' ... );
```

Now in business logic

```
if( empty( $relation )  ){

  // No relation exists

}elseif( in_array( 'invoice', $relation ) ){

   $message->set_message("Cannot delete Sales Order, Invoice exists.");

}else ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from information_schema.table_constraints
where constraint_schema = DATABASE();

select * from information_schema.key_column_usage
where constraint_schema = DATABASE();
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2764fa/8)

Comment: Could you please explain ?

Comment: Sure, preparing sqlfiddle demo.

Comment: Added example where you see existing relation with table and column names.

Comment: But where i put the value ? in my example 34.